# How do I input 4-byte UTF-8 characters?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, astral-plane

I am writing a small app which I need to test with utf-8 characters of different number of byte lengths.

I can input unicode characters to test that are encoded in utf-8 with 1,2 and 3 bytes just fine by doing, for example:

```
string in = "pi = \u3a0";
```

But how do I get a unicode character that is encoded with 4-bytes? I have tried:

```
string in = "aegan check mark = \u10102";
```

Which as far as I understand should be outputting . But when I print that out I get ᴶ0

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I got it to work by adding leading zeros:

```
string in = "\U00010102";
```

Wish I had thought of that sooner :)

Comment: What method are you using to print?  Is it unicode aware?

Comment: I just use cout with Terminal.app which works well with unicode.

Comment: Ha! I didn't see that edit while composing my answer, should have hit reply sooner.

Comment: Thanks anyway, got some good tips from your answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a longer form of escape in the pattern `\U` followed by eight digits, rather than `\u` followed by four digits. This is also used in Java and Python, amongst others:

```
>>> '\xf0\x90\x84\x82'.decode("UTF-8")
u'\U00010102'
```

However, if you are using byte strings, why not just escape each byte like above, rather than relying on the compiler to convert the escape to a UTF-8 string? This would seem to be more portable as well - if I compile the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "narrow: " << std::string("\uFF0E").length() <<
        " utf8: " << std::string("\xEF\xBC\x8E").length() <<
        " wide: " << std::wstring(L"\uFF0E").length() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "narrow: " << std::string("\U00010102").length() <<
        " utf8: " << std::string("\xF0\x90\x84\x82").length() <<
        " wide: " << std::wstring(L"\U00010102").length() << std::endl;
}
```

On win32 with my current options cl gives:

`warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\UD800DD02' cannot be represented in the current code page (932)`

The compiler tries to convert all unicode escapes in byte strings to the system code page, which unlike UTF-8 cannot represent all unicode characters. Oddly it has understood that `\U00010102` is `\uD800\uDD02` in UTF-16 (its internal unicode representation) and mangled the escape in the error message...

When run, the program prints:

```
narrow: 2 utf8: 3 wide: 1
narrow: 2 utf8: 4 wide: 2
```

Note that the UTF-8 bytestrings and the wide strings are correct, but the compiler failed to convert `"\U00010102"`, giving the byte string `"??"`, an incorrect result.

Comment: Contrary to your second sentence, `\Uxxxxxxxx` is not used in Java: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.3

Comment: A reason not to use the hex escapes to manually encode things is because that requires doing the encoding manually and obfuscates the code. Better to use Unicode escape sequences and to tell the compiler to use UTF-8 as the execution charset. Contact your compiler vendor if it doesn't already support that.